# Passing Variables From ListSelectionListeners and ActionListeners

Tags: java, user-interface, static, actionlistener, listselectionlistener

I'm having issues properly passing values/variables as result of `ListSelectionListener` and `ActionListener` methods from my GUI.  Basically, I am receiving (6) six errors stemming from the same problem.

`non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context`

I've had problems before with fully understanding this error and thought that I had it.  But once we started to learn GUI's and how to implement them, I have lost my understanding again.  Ideally, I wish to take an end-users decision(s) and pass that along to the main GUI function.  Below is a portion of `public class EnemyPanel extends JPanel` that feeds off of my main `JFrame` of my program.  Everything was fine until I attempted to do the following:

```
public class PlayerPanel extends JPanel
{

private JPanel compPlayerPanel;
private JPanel playerPanel;
private JList playerList;
private JPanel playerListPanel;
private JLabel playerImageLabel;
private JPanel playerImagePanel;
private JPanel buttonPanel;
private JButton selctButton;
private ImageIcon playerImage;
private String playerSlctd;
public int playerChoice;
public int playerWeaponChoice;


private void buildWeaponSelectionPanel()
{
    weaponPanel = new JPanel();

    weaponListPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    weaponListPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 85));
    weaponListPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    weaponPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(weaponPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    weaponList = new JList(weapons);

    weaponList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    weaponList.addListSelectionListener(new WeaponListListener());
    weaponListPanel.add(weaponList);
    weaponPanel.add(weaponListPanel);
}
private class WeaponListListener implements ListSelectionListener
{
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
    {
        weaponSlctd = (String) weaponList.getSelectedValue();

        if (weaponSlctd == "Mace")
        {
            weaponImage = new ImageIcon("Mace.png");
            playerWeaponChoice = 1;
        }
        else if(weaponSlctd == "Short Sword")
        {
            weaponImage = new ImageIcon("ShortSword.png");
            playerWeaponChoice = 2;
        }
        else if(weaponSlctd == "Long Sword")
        {
            weaponImage = new ImageIcon("LongSword.png");
            playerWeaponChoice = 3;
        }
        else if(weaponSlctd == "Axe")
        {
            weaponImage = new ImageIcon("Axe.png");
            playerWeaponChoice = 4;
        }

        weaponImageLabel.setIcon(weaponImage);

        weaponImageLabel.setText(null);
    }
}

public int getPlayerWeaponSelected()
{
    return playerWeaponChoice;
}
```

Basically, the end-user selects from a `JList` and depending on their selection, a .png displays and their selection is recorded as `weaponSlctd` in the method above.  My issue is that I would like to take that value and use it in the following method of my `JFrame`:

```
private class RunButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
                    playerWeaponType = PlayerPanel.getPlayerWeaponSelected();
    }
}
```

I have a lot more code but I don't feel it is necessary to post it all due to several reasons.  A) the player follows a template that other of my `JLabels` are designed after.  B) The error during compilation arises from the method `getPlayerSelected()` which is dependent on the `WeaponListListener` class.  I am positive that it is the way I'm attempting to pass the integer `weaponSlctd` from one method to the next, and from one `extended JPanel` to the parent `JFrame` that is calling it all.

I'd appreciate some help and insight into what I'm doing wrong and/or how I can change my code that will permit me to pass `JList`, `JButton`, and other end-user selection variables into a main method.  I'm having a disconnect on the appropriate way of doing so.  I've read some of the other threads concerning static and non-static variables and they have helped me in the past.  But this is the first time I'm building and manipulating the `swing` and `awt` extensions to help with a GUI.  I believe that for some reason incorporating the `ActionListener` and `ListSelectionListener` functionality into the mix has tossed me for a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
non-static variable cannot be referenced from a static context
```

I used to get this error so much...Okay, so you have two options as of what to do:

1. You make your fields static
2. Make your methods non-static by creating an instance of the class (object)

**When using that method, I suggest you make an object of the class, and call it by doing:**

```
Object.method();
```

Or, you can just make the fields themselves static, and access it through static variables.

Static can only access more static. Static cannot access instance.

Static methods and variables do not belong to an instance of a class, which is why you cannot use them with an object. So, again, either make everything static, or access the method and variable using an object, which is an instance of the class.

Comment: I don't fully understand A) What it means to implement `Object.method()` from your example based on my code and B) fully understand what I'm doing is causing this error.  I have read peoples explanations on static vs non-static and still don't get it.  I guess I need someone to "baby" it down for me because somehow I'm still failing to connect the dots here.

Comment: @Pwrcdr87 **A)**Okay, in java, you can make a thing called an object. This object is an _instance_ of a class. So, if a method is in a certain class, you can make an object **of** that class, and call the method by doing `Object.method()`. **B)** Forget about static for one second. Just think about a regular method, okay? Lets call it method A. Method A is in class `myClass`. So, to access A, we create an object of `myClass` and call the method A by doing `myClass.A`. Now, there are things called `static` methods. Don't worry about what it means right now, just know, to access them

Comment: @Pwrcdr87 you will need to just call the method. That's it. Forget about static for now then, it is advanced, but just create the object as I suggested in A.

Comment: Ok.  I gotchya.  Working on this project all day and my brain is fried.  Thanks for your help.  I think I understand better now!